# Bash, run multiple commands simultaneously, wait for N to finish before spawning more

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, shell

Alright, so I've tried gnu parallel and there's some quirks about getting that to work that makes it not possible for me to use.

Ultimately I'd love to just be able to do something like this:

```
for modelplot in /${rfolder}/${mplotsfolder}/${mname}/$mscript.gs
do

for regionplot in $mregions
do
opengrads -bclx "${modelplot}.gs $regionplot ${plotimage} ${date} ${run} ${gribfile} ${modelplot}" && wait -n
done

done
```

But I can't seem to find a way to limit the spawning of background processes to a specific number. Someone mentioned doing:

```
for i in {1..10}; do echo "${i} & (( count ++ > 5 )) && wait -n; done
```

Should do it, but I can't really verify if it is working that way. It seems like it just spawns them all instantly. I'm assuming the output in terminal of that should be: echo 1, echo 2, echo 3, echo 4, echo 5. Then echo 6, echo 7, echo 8, echo 9, echo 10.

I'm just trying to spawn, say 5, iterations of a loop, wait for those to finish and then spawn the next 5, wait for those to finish, spawn the next 5, etc until the loop is done.

Comment: You should read about [parallel](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/parallel.1.html)

Comment: @glennjackman Mentioned in the first sentence as non-viable (though I wonder why not).

Comment: I'd love to use parallel, but I can't do something like this: parallel -j5 opengrads -bclx ::: ${cdf}${mscript}.gs  ::: ${mregions} ::: ${fileprefix} ::: ${mscript}

Because cdf=/path/to/dir/ and it's only applied to the first run. Also, .gs is only applied to the last run.

I might end up using parallel for the nicety of it but I'll have to re-work the way I handle my var's.

Comment: Ahh, that's the other thing. I really just need to run the command like once... per $mscript and interate through mregions and file prefix.

mscript="script1 script2 script3" mregions="us uk canada" fileprefix="sflux pgrb"

From my testing, parallel would run every possible iteration of those, which is why I originally used a for loop since it would run how I posted, which was exactly how it was needed.

Answer (score 4):

Each time you start a background job, increment a count. When that count reaches 5 (or whatever), `wait` for all background jobs to complete, then reset the count to 0 and resume starting background jobs.

```
p_count=0
for modelplot in /${rfolder}/${mplotsfolder}/${mname}/$mscript.gs; do
  for regionplot in $mregions; do
      opengrads -bclx "${modelplot}.gs $regionplot ${plotimage} ${date} ${run} ${gribfile} ${modelplot}" &
      if (( ++p_count == 5 )); then
          wait
          p_count=0
      fi
    done
  done
done
```

It is surprisingly tricky to keep exactly 5, rather than at most 5, jobs running in the background in shell. (`wait -n` lets you know when *a* job has finished, but not *how many* have finished.) To keep the machine busy, a tool like `xargs` or `parallel` is more appropriate.

Comment: I have no problem with keeping the machine busy as all scripts will have almost identical processing time. Sure I would have some wasted time, but running 5 at a time verus individually I'm already saving tons of time.

Is there anyway to "verify" (I tend to try simple echo "waiting" & sleep 10 which tends to not work as expected when sending things to the background) that it's spawning 5, waiting until all close before spawning the next 5 iterations?

Comment: You can run `jobs -p` just before the `wait` call to see the current set of background processes.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments it is pretty unclear what you want.

But using the `{= =}` construct you can get almost anything in the arguments.

Append .gs only on the first run:

```
parallel echo {}'{= if($job->seq() == 1) { $_ = ".gs" } else { $_="" } =}' ::: a b c
```

Append .gs only on the last run:

```
parallel echo {}'{= if($job->seq() == $Global::JobQueue->total_jobs() ) { $_ = ".gs" } else { $_="" } =}' ::: a b c
```

Disregarding the comments and looking only at the loop in the question the solution is:

```
parallel --header : opengrads -bclx "{modelplot}.gs {regionplot} ${plotimage} ${date} ${run} ${gribfile} {modelplot}" ::: modelplot /${rfolder}/${mplotsfolder}/${mname}/$mscript.gs ::: regionplot $mregions
```

Comment: Very interesting sir! I'm going to have to look at that last one as it looks like that might be what I need.